# Read json object in php file from app

Tags: php, json

I have designed an android app from which I am sending data in json to my php file which is on server. Json is :

```
[
{
"user_id":"11",
"check_id":"38",
"pcode_id":"14",
"platform_id":"2",
"vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
"date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
"status":"completed",
"description":"Check for proper insert of the connector and loose",
"result":true
},
{
"user_id":"11",
"check_id":"39",
"pcode_id":"14",
"platform_id":"2",
"vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
"date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
"status":"completed",
"description":"Damaged\/Cracked",
"result":false
}]
```

Now I have to read this data and separatly put into arrays one by one in php file. So that I can calculate it and inesert into proper table.
Please help me. App using post method with json encode. My php file code is

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($json);
foreach($json as $a)
echo $a['user_id'];{
echo $a['check_id'];
echo $a['pcode_id'];
echo $a['platform_id'];
echo $a['date'];
echo $a['status'];
echo $a['description'];
echo $a['result'];
}
```

Comment: What is the issue are you getting?

Comment: Displaying nothing...

Comment: Are you getting response in `print_r($json);`?

Comment: `<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in `

Comment: change foreach($json as $a)
echo $a['user_id'];{  to  foreach($json as $a) {
echo $a['user_id'];  may be its typo but if its not then change it.

Comment: check my answer below @BahirjiNaik

Comment: try to read with $_POST instead of file_get_contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the JSON properties as array keys. But what you have is a StdObject so you have got to use the ->.

Let's say that you have an URL like this: http://mydata.data/somefile.php That will spit out the JSON data. All you have to do is:

$data - file_get_contents('http://mydata.data/somefile.php');

Please give this a try:

```
   <?php
    $data = '[
    {
    "user_id":"11",
    "check_id":"38",
    "pcode_id":"14",
    "platform_id":"2",
    "vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
    "date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
    "status":"completed",
    "description":"Check for proper insert of the connector and loose",
    "result":true
    },
    {
    "user_id":"11",
    "check_id":"39",
    "pcode_id":"14",
    "platform_id":"2",
    "vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
    "date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
    "status":"completed",
    "description":"Damaged\/Cracked",
    "result":false
    }]';

    $json = json_decode($data);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<br><br>loop';

    foreach($json as $a) {
    echo $a->user_id;
    echo $a->check_id;
    echo $a->pcode_id;
    echo $a->platform_id;
    echo $a->date;
    echo $a->status;
    echo $a->description;
    echo $a->result;
    }
```

Comment: This `$data` is coming from android app. So first of all we have to catch json. Please check json

Comment: To get the JSON data, use file_get_contents; That will put all your contents into a string. After that, use json_decode.

Comment: This code is working perfectly..but now I want to fetch data from submitted json. So when I am trying this `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");` instead of data variable it showing error : `pre></pre><br><br>loop<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`

Comment: This php code is a service. Which is reading data from app. When I am clicking on button in my android app, it sending me json to php file.

Comment: Right. So lets say that your file is named json_from_android.php. And your URL is http://mydata.data/. Try this: $data = file_get_contents('http://mydata.data/json_from_android.php'); (include the http)

Comment: Is your service doing a POST?

Comment: This code is in test.php file. and android app is sending json to test.php file which is on server.

Comment: You can also use file_get_contents('php://input') if the service is doing a POST. I prefer to just use file_get_contents(uri goes here). Hope that helps you. The code I posted works, I have tried it myself.

Comment: Yes this is working..but I am trying to send data from android software to this file. So what should be uri now ?

Comment: With all the due respect, that is not a PHP question then. That is more of an Android question. You are asking a question that is beyond the scope of your original question. I would choose an answer as your Best Answer and then create another question on a Stackoverflow Android section. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` decode json and return as object. If you want array them pass `true` as second parameter

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
print_r($json);
foreach($json as $a)
{
echo $a['user_id'];
echo $a['check_id'];
echo $a['pcode_id'];
echo $a['platform_id'];
echo $a['date'];
echo $a['status'];
echo $a['description'];
echo $a['result'];
}
```

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);` is not working.
This php code is a service. Which is reading data from app. When I am clicking on button in my android app, it sending me json to php file. Now I am going to read that json further in above php file

Answer (score 0):

By default `json_decode` outputs object instead of array , if you need to get array as output pass `true` in `json_decode` as

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
print_r($json);
foreach($json as $a)
echo $a['user_id'];{
echo $a['check_id'];
echo $a['pcode_id'];
echo $a['platform_id'];
echo $a['date'];
echo $a['status'];
echo $a['description'];
echo $a['result'];
}
```

Comment: This php code is a service. Which is reading data from app. When I am clicking on button in my android app, it sending me json to php file. Now I am going to read that json further in above php file

Comment: what you get in `print_r($json);`

Comment: `Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/..../api/test.php</b> on line <b>38`

Comment: Comments all the lines after print and then run the file and the output

Comment: It means you are getting null value or blank output, in that case you should make sure that you get something from your android app

Answer (score 0):

Try it : -

```
 <?php 
    $a='[
    {
    "user_id":"11",
    "check_id":"38",
    "pcode_id":"14",
    "platform_id":"2",
    "vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
    "date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
    "status":"completed",
    "description":"Check for proper insert of the connector and loose",
    "result":true
    },
    {
    "user_id":"11",
    "check_id":"39",
    "pcode_id":"14",
    "platform_id":"2",
    "vin":"MA11340DP0DN09661",
    "date":"2017-06-09-10-48-25",
    "status":"completed",
    "description":"Damaged\/Cracked",
    "result":false
    }]';

    $json = json_decode($a);

    for($i=0; $i<count($json); $i++)
    {
        echo "user_id :- ".$json[$i]->user_id."<br>";
        echo "check_id :- ".$json[$i]->check_id."<br>";
        echo "pcode_id :- ".$json[$i]->pcode_id."<br>";
        echo "platform_id :- ".$json[$i]->platform_id."<br>";
        echo "vin :- ".$json[$i]->vin."<br>";
        echo "date :- ".$json[$i]->date."<br>";
        echo "status :- ".$json[$i]->status."<br>";
        echo "description :- ".$json[$i]->description."<br>";
        echo "result :- ".$json[$i]->result."<br><hr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Out Put : -
[image]

Comment: Its working for php file bu this php code is a service. Which is reading data from app. When I am clicking on button in my android app, it sending me json to php file. Now I am going to read that json further in above php file. So now how to read json (POST method) in php file ?